# webpack throw error "uv__finish_close: Assertion `handle->flags & UV_CLOSING' failed."

Tags: webpack

I was running `webpack --progress` on my VPS box.

Whenever it reached around 60%, it would throw:

```
59% 222/271 build modulesnode: ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:209: 
uv__finish_close: Assertion `handle->flags & UV_CLOSING' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced same error with sass-loader, if that is your case, i fixed it with switching to `node-sass@2.0.1` and `sass-loader@0.4.2`. There is issue on [github](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/713)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm rebuild`. This will recompile your dependencies.